# How can I bypass a third-party app from taking over the screen and preventing keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, applications

I have a distance testing app I’m using, and it uses some malicious techniques to close Finder, prevent keyboard shortcuts, and make itself fullscreen. I would like to bypass this ability for my own nefarious purposes, but I don't know how. I've tried Command-Tab, shortcut keys, and more, but none of them are working. Is there any way I can institute a system automation, command line shortcut, or something similar to bypass this app's system control?

(By the way, when the app first launched, it requested permission for Desktop folder access (that's where the app is located on my Mac) and System Events control.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Not sure how this can be answered without knowing what the app is that "uses some malicious techniques to close Finder, prevent keyboard shortcuts, and make itself fullscreen." (and just what your "nefarious purposes" are).

Comment: My Spidey Sense tells me this is a distance learning/testing app.  This type of thing is ***very*** prevalent in the Edu space, but not in the business space because in business, it makes no sense to cut the user off from the rest of their compute resources.  Name of the app, please?

Comment: Alright, you got me. It's a testing app. And no, I'm not bypassing it to cheat or anything. If I wanted to do that, I would just use a separate device. I'm actually more curious about figuring out how exactly the app does this, and how you can get around it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works (and I am very curious as to how it does work since I'm a dev), but I have found that most Locked Down Browsers/Locked in apps can be exited by   pressing the media `pause/play` (same as the F8 key) key along with the `window manager` key (F3 key)  at the same time twice exits the app until you go back in it. It seems as though this escapes it because the `pause/play` key opens up iTunes and the other key opens the window switcher.

Comment: How does it do it?  It looks at events registered with the system.  Every time you press a key, the system has to know about it.  Some things you can intercept - like key presses.  This is how karabiner works.  Others, you can disable like opening a window full screen and disabling the minimize buttons.  But even if you do find a way to take focus away from the window (another event), the software will "see" it and record it for posterity.